# How To Add HTTP PROXY to Apple TV via Windows 7

Tags: tv

On the iPhone / iPad In setting - Wifi  - Your Wifi - There is a HTTP PROXY section which you can change

I see no option for this on Apple TV is there anyway to add HTTP PROXY to Apple TV  but via Windows 7

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish specifically?  There might be a different approach.

Comment: @Tyson , I am trying to bypass country restriction to watch contents on Apple TV

Comment: Something like a vpn for Apple TV not via Route

Comment: so why not follow these instructions (link at end of comment) on the win7 computer to set it up to share it's internet wirelessly, then have the apple tv join that network (SSID) instead of your routers? The computer would then share it's VPN connection which is what I think you're wanting... if that's the idea then I'll write it up as a better answer so you can accept it.  http://www.practicallynetworked.com/networking/create_a%20virtual_wireless_router_with_windows.htm

Comment: @Tyson , This is what i am trying to do , For example i am in England and i want to watch something on the internet but the website is only restricted to China's IP address , I know how to bypass it via computer and smartphone / tablet but i don't know how to bypass it on smartbox because it does not have the same setting ,    while on the iphone /ipad if i go to setting - wifi - my wifi and change the setting there  i can watch the restricted content but on the apple tv i don't see an option for http proxy , How do i add http proxy settings to apple tv ? Hope this help

Comment: So when i open apple tv i can just watch content and don't have to open my computer as well

Comment: Yea I get what you're trying to do, but since the setting doesn't exist-- I just thought I would suggest and alternate that should work.  I didn't type it as an answer tho because I have never actually tried it, but in theory it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream you have more options than an HTTP proxy. You can use a VPN or a DNS proxy. A VPN will have more bandwidth overhead because of the encryption, but if you have a very fast connection it should work fine.

Another option is a DNS proxy. This allows you to virtually change your location by using a different DNS server, while using your normal internet connection. If your Apple TV is behind a router, I would set both the Apple TV and the Router to use the DNS proxy.

It's why I use IronSocket for VPN, DNS, HTTP, SOCKS5 etc. because they are all included and its cheap. Here is the Apple TV setup page for your reference: https://ironsocket.com/setup/apple-tv